# How to do SEO for dynamically loaded videos

Tags: seo, html

I got an vimeo-video which is loaded into an overlay-div, if the user clicks a button. How can I provide SEO on my website for the dynamically inserted video-iframe? Can I just meta-tags in the markup of the button?

HTML

```
 <div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
 <h2><span itemprop="name">my name</span></h2>
 <meta itemprop="duration" content="T01M54S" />
 <meta itemprop="thumbnailURL" content="my thumb" />
  <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="https://my video" />
 <div id="schema-videoobject"><object width="1280" height="720">
```

Comment: are there dedicated pages for the videos, ie each video has its own page? in that case you'd want to add titles, meta desc etc on each page.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the embed code from youtube. There are many ways of accomplish this. I'll give you two links with well described tutorial.

**How to do it:** https://www.distilled.net/blog/seo/getting-links-and-seo-value-from-your-youtube-videos/

**This is further reading:** https://www.distilled.net/blog/social-media/youtube/youtube-seo/#seotips